# get item behind sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Using jQuery UI sortable, is there a way of getting which element is behind the item being dragged?

If I have 5 items and start dragging one of them, while I'm over another one I should be able to trigger a mouseenter event...but it seems that this kind of events are not firing while dragging.

To better se what I'm talking about, see this example: move the mouse over the items and you will see a red dotted border, now start dragging one item and the rest of them will no longer get the red border.

I would like the retrieve which item is behind the current draggable. (The red border is just an illustration, I would perform some js code)

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; }
  html>body #sortable li { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
  .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }

  .red_border{border: 1px dotted red;}
```

JS

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    $("li").mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("red_border");
    });

    $("li").mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("red_border");
    });    
  } );
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/d12j7qw3/

Comment: I would assume you would have to know the X,Y coordinate values for mouse position in order to accomplish this. (I may be wrong).

Comment: Can make use of `sort` callback.

Comment: Suspect you will have an issue with the Place Holder. See more: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xv15vkts/

Comment: @Twisty I don't see any red border while dragging

Comment: Do you want the placeholder to have a red border?

Comment: @Twisty I want a red border on the item that is behind the current dragged element

Comment: That is the placeholder as far as I can tell. Try: `placeholder: "ui-state-highlight red_border"`

Comment: Actually, I adjusted CSS: `.ui-state-highlight {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}`

Comment: Move the mouse over the items before doing any sort, you will see a red border caused by a mouseenter event...now star dragging and you will notice the event no longe fires. read my answer again.

Comment: @MatíasCánepa I understand what you're saying and I have yet to get a definitive answer. Are you trying to add a border to the placeholder? Cause if you drag an item over the list, the placeholder appears. Using that CSS, I have been able to add a red border to it, which is what you said you wanted. Also you have not posted an answer, only a question. Maybe a screen shot of the issue would help.

Comment: I don't want to touch the placeholder at all, In fact, I never mentioned that element and I don't want to apply any css to it.